# cannot assign state in react Component constructor, err "is not assignable to type 'Readonly'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a common search Components for wap and web

when I'try to assign state in constructor, err: '*is not assignable to type 'Readonly*'

```
export interface SearchProps {
    searchValue: string;
    keyword: string;
    words: string[];
    suggestList: Array<{name: string, value: string}>;
    searchHistories: SearchHistory[];
}

export interface SearchState  {
    searchValue: string;
    keyword: string;
    words: string[];
    suggestList: Array<{name: string, value: string}>;
    searchHistories: SearchHistory[];
}

class CommonSearch<P extends SearchProps, S extends SearchState> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props: P) {
        super(props);
        // err 'is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
        this.state = {
            searchValue: "",
            keyword: "",
            words: [],
            suggestList: [],
            searchHistories: []
        }
    }
```